# url.content showing the same video

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Please help me find what I am missing. url.content is not returning each item's video in a foreach loop instead it is showing the same video for each element. I would like to access each video in the videofilepath column of my table and display it on a modal (still a work in progress).

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
        <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" 
        src='@item.PosterFilePath'alt="thumbnail" />

        <strong> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)</strong>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        <br>
        <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)</strong>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
        <br>
        <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre)</strong>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
        <br>
        <strong> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)</strong>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
        <br>
        <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rating)</strong>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rating)
        <br>
        <div class="">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ajax">Watch now</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"><span class="glyphicon-download"></span>Download</button>
        </div>

        <br>

        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })

    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="ajax">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                   <h3>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                   <video id="video" poster="~/Images/algo.jpg"
                           controls="controls"
                           loop="loop">
                        <source src="@Url.Content(item.VideoFilePath)" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" id="btnClose" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon-folder-close"></span>Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Download</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: what is inside in VideoFilePath? Check your database

Comment: Is it possible that all the items in your model contain the same video URL? Please make sure that the items have different values for VideoFilePath property. Can the VideoFilePath property in your model be static?

Comment: the relative path to the video's they are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your modal *div* needs to have a unique Id. If you have the Id of the video for example as part of the Model, you could prepend or append it:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ajax@(Model.VideoId)"
```

and the same with the button that invokes it:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ajax@(Model.VideoId)">Watch now</button>
```